# Javascript - Convert UTC time to a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a time string in HH:mm format (example - 13:45). I am using rc-time-picker which by default formats it using moment, which converts it to GMT. I have been trying to convert this output time to a specific timezone (different than my server's timezone), but to no success.

I have looked at the following options, but haven't had luck because of the mentioned reasons next to them:

1. Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset() - but this gives you an offset compared to your server timezone, and not a custom timezone that you can enter
2. moment library - In order to convert time to a specific timezone, this requires a utcOffset parameter, which I do not have. Then I thought, I can get utcOffset from another library, so I tried
3. moment-timezone library - I tried using the zone.utcOffset(timestamp) function, but then it uses zone (example 'America/Los_Angeles')) and not timezone (example 'PDT'). I only have the timezone, so this option got ruled out too.

This sounds like something really simple to do and others must have faced issues with this. Am I overthinking a straight-forward solution? Can someone please help me here or point me to some better solutions?

Comment: Is the timezone picked by the user? Because each timezone has a fixed offset from GMT, so all you need to do is shift the Date by the offset, as far as I understand. For instance my local timezone is GMT+2 right now, so a timestamp in GMT + 120 minutes is the desired time. In other words, all you need is a static list of timezones and their offsets.

Comment: Yes, the timezone is picked by the user. I did indeed think of creating a static list, but wasn't convinced if that is the best way to do it.

Comment: PDT is a time zone abbreviation, not a time zone identifier.  Indeed, many such abbreviations are not unique, so they cannot be used as identifiers (CST for example).